# Does Google Chrome cache rendered SVGs? If not, how should we optimize SVGs for Chrome rendering?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, svg, optimization, render

## Problem

The [live site is here](https://tiadaguru.webflow.io/), created in Webflow. As you hover over menu items, the background-img changes by setting other backgrounds to 0% opacity & setting this background to 100% opacity.  My problem is with the first SVG (titled "390 KB SVG"), which has ~ 1,000 elements.

In Firefox, Edge, and Internet Explorer, this relatively large SVG is rendered once and then cached for displaying immediately every time after. **In Chrome, the same SVG is forcibly re-rendered on each hover event**, costing between 150ms (i5-8600K) and 600 ms (i5-6200U) each time.

**Can we somehow enable rendered-SVG caching in Chrome? Or improve the SVG rendering performance overall?** Smaller SVGs render quick enough in Chrome.

## What I've already tried

The SVG is a 2500px x 1250px, 1 precision SVG exported from Adobe Illustrator CC 2019. The raw ouput from Adobe Illustrator is 762 KB. I'd already optimized the problematic 762 KB SVG down to 390 KB:

1. Lowered precision to 1 after increasing artboard size [as described here](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-and-manually-improving-svg-optimization/).
2. [Used SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to remove almost all metadata.
3. [Used Vecta.IO's SVG Nano tool](https://vecta.io/nano) to further minify and compress.
4. [Used SVGito](https://sketchmaster.com/svg-optimizer) to re-use identical paths.

While it surely renders faster than the initial output, it still takes ~500+ ms to render on slower systems.

I've also tried alternative ways to change the backgrounds, like display: none or, instead of hiding backgrounds via 0% opacity, only going to 1% opacity: bt even at 1%, Chrome requires a re-render to bring it from 1% to 100% opacity.

## SVG code & how it's being called

The SVG's code can be viewed here: https://codepen.io/TG2-/pen/EBXEGO

The SVGs are called via Javascript, like so, with [Webflow's built-in JavaScript](https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5d0a2d1817472e726fb59fba/js/webflow.265591220.js) (called "Interactions IX2"):

```
            }, {
                "id": "a-11-n-7",
                "actionTypeId": "STYLE_OPACITY",
                "config": {
                    "delay": 0,
                    "easing": "",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "target": {
                        "id": "92202c53-63db-1dc1-831b-53546fc80f59"
                    },
                    "value": 0,
                    "unit": ""
                }
            }, {
                "id": "a-11-n-8",
                "actionTypeId": "STYLE_OPACITY",
                "config": {
                    "delay": 0,
                    "easing": "",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "target": {
                        "id": "92202c53-63db-1dc1-831b-53546fc80f60"
                    },
                    "value": 1,
                    "unit": ""
                }
            }]
```

## Expected result:

1) Hovering to the first menu item ("390 KB SVG")  should change the background image relatively immediately (ideally under 50 ms) in Chrome

(*either via caching the rendered SVG, like other browsers, or through increasing the render performance in Chrome)

## Actual result:

1) Hovering to the first menu item ("390 KB SVG") changes the background image after 200 ms to 600 ms, depending on the speed of the user's CPU.

---

## SOLUTION (credit to Kaiido & Paul LeBeua)

Change the SVG pattern to an SVG fill. Here is the **old SVG, using patterns**:

```
<style>
        <![CDATA[.B {
            fill: url(#C)
        }

        .C {
            fill: url(#B)
        }

        .D {
            fill: url(#A)
        }

        .E {
            fill: url(#E)
        }

        .F {
            fill: url(#D)
        }

        ]]>
    </style>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="A" width="3" height="3" patternTransform="matrix(50 0 0 50 -892 -730.5)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path fill="#7c26cc" d="M0 0h3v3H0z" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="B" width="3" height="3" patternTransform="matrix(50 0 0 50 -892 -730.5)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path fill="#b45ffe" d="M0 0h3v3H0z" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="C" width="3" height="3" patternTransform="matrix(50 0 0 50 -892 -730.5)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path fill="#b9b9b9" d="M0 0h3v3H0z" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="D" width="3" height="3" patternTransform="matrix(50 0 0 50 -892 -730.5)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path fill="#e1e1e1" d="M0 0h3v3H0z" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="E" width="3" height="3" patternTransform="matrix(50 0 0 50 -892 -730.5)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path fill="#e3d3ed" d="M0 0h3v3H0z" />
        </pattern>
```

Here is the **new SVG, using fill**:

```
<style><![CDATA[.B {
    fill: #b9b9b9
}

.C {
    fill: #b45ffe
}

.D {
    fill: #7c26cc
}

.E {
    fill: #e3d3ed
}

.F {
    fill: #e1e1e1
}

]]></style>
```

Comment: For one, what's this idea of using <pattern> for filling solid colors?

Comment: PatternTransform, you're right, really serves no purpose here versus a fill. It'll take me some time to figure out how to change that cleanly, but I'll definitely start that for now.

Comment: @Kaiido, you were right! Replacing the patterns with fill instantly cured the issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kaiido's instinct appears to be correct. It does seem to be related to the use of `<pattern>` elements in that SVG.  If you change the CSS in that SVG to use colours directly, the SVG is rendered much faster.

Eg: all you need to do is copy the colour from the pattern to the associated style:

```
.A { fill: #7c26cc; }
```

etc

The use of patterns here serves no purpose.

Comment: It worked like a charm! It loads instantly now. I've been struggling for a week now! Thank you so very much.  I'd +1 if I could.

Comment: And thank you for showing me how to edit the SVG code directly: that direct replacement method is very easy to implement. I recommend this method for anyone who's getting the same export issues with Adobe Illustrator 2019 CC. For others, I've added the before/after in the original post.

The new SVG is live on the website!